# If $\delta(G)\geq k$, does it implies $G$ contains a $k$-regular subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph, and minimum degree $\delta(G)\geq k$, does $G$ contain a $k$-regular subgraph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick a square with the diagonals, as a graph on FIVE vertices, where the vertices are the four corners and the intersection of the diagonals.

[image: Drawing of graph]

Then $\delta(G)\geq 3$ but it is trivial to see that $G$ contains no $3$-regular subgraph.